# How to swift bluetooth connect device?

Tags: swift, bluetooth, connect

```
import Foundation


struct BluetoothStruct {
    var name : String?
    var rssi : NSNumber!
    var advertisementData: [String : Any]!
    var uuid : String!
}



import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CBCentralManagerDelegate,CBPeripheralDelegate {

    var allBluetoothArray = [BluetoothStruct]();
    var arrayPeripehral = [CBPeripheral]()
    var cbCentralManager : CBCentralManager?

    var manager:CBCentralManager!
    var peripheral:CBPeripheral!

    //MARK: - IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!


    //MARK: - IBActions
    @IBAction func refreshAction(_ sender: Any) {
        allBluetoothArray = [BluetoothStruct]();
        table.reloadData();

        cbCentralManager?.stopScan();
        cbCentralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil);

    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        table.delegate = self;
        table.dataSource = self;

        cbCentralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil);
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return allBluetoothArray.count;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BluetoothCell", for: indexPath) as! BluetoothTableViewCell;

        if let name = allBluetoothArray[indexPath.row].name {
            cell.deviceName.text = "Bluetooth Aygıt Adı: \(name)"
        }else{
            cell.deviceName.text = "Bluetooth Aygıt Adı: \(allBluetoothArray[indexPath.row].uuid)"
        }

        cell.deviceSignal.text = "RSSI: \(allBluetoothArray[indexPath.row].rssi)"


        return cell;
    }


    //MARK: - Bluetooth Functions
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
            central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil);
        }else{
            print("Bluetooth'un çalışmıyor, lütfen düzelt");
        }
    }


    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

        var bluetoothStruct = BluetoothStruct();

        if let name = peripheral.name{
            bluetoothStruct.name = name;
        }

        bluetoothStruct.uuid = peripheral.identifier.uuidString;
        bluetoothStruct.rssi = RSSI;
        bluetoothStruct.advertisementData = advertisementData;

        if !(allBluetoothArray.contains(where: {$0.uuid == peripheral.identifier.uuidString})){
            allBluetoothArray.append(bluetoothStruct);
            arrayPeripehral.append(peripheral)
            //print(allBluetoothArray)
        }

        table.reloadData();
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(allBluetoothArray[indexPath.row])
        print(allBluetoothArray[indexPath.row].name)
        print(allBluetoothArray[indexPath.row].rssi)
        print(allBluetoothArray[indexPath.row].advertisementData)
        print(allBluetoothArray[indexPath.row].uuid)

        let peripheral = arrayPeripehral[indexPath.row]
        cbCentralManager?.connect(peripheral,options: nil)
    }


}
```

Comment: Only code in your question won't help. Add description about problem you are facing.

Comment: Bluetooth connect not device. How to connect  bluetooth device

Comment: Why do you think the device does not connect? You haven't implemented the [centralManager:didConnectPeripheral:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate/1518969-centralmanager), so your code won't be notified about a successful connection. What do you expect to happen when the device connects?

Comment: So what? And again: What do you expect to happen when the device connects?

Comment: Device connect message send ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to add the following to your ViewController

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {

    peripheral.delegate = self

    print("Connected peripheral: \(peripheral.name ?? "UNKNOWN NAME")")
}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {

    for service in peripheral.services ?? [] {
        print("Discovered service: \(service.uuid.uuidString)")
    }
}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {

    for char in service.characteristics ?? [] {
        print("Discovered char: \(char.uuid.uuidString)")
    }
}
```

Or set the delegate before connecting to the device

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(allBluetoothArray[indexPath.row])
    print(allBluetoothArray[indexPath.row].name)
    print(allBluetoothArray[indexPath.row].rssi)
    print(allBluetoothArray[indexPath.row].advertisementData)
    print(allBluetoothArray[indexPath.row].uuid)

    let peripheral = arrayPeripehral[indexPath.row]

    peripheral.delegate = self // <=== THIS LINE

    cbCentralManager?.connect(peripheral,options: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. How to send message ?

Comment: What message? Your question is not about message)

Comment: He would like that you write the rest of the application for him as well...

Comment: Connect to device message send how to ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a message you should use the function ***writeValue*** of current peripheral you are connected

**For example**

```
let messageToSend = "HelloWorld!"
peripheral.writeValue(messageToSend.data(using: .utf8)!, for: char, type: .withResponse)
```

**To check if the function handle some errors you can use this delegate**

```
 func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) { }
```

**To find all characteristics**

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        if let services = peripheral.services {
            for service in services {
                peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
            }
        }
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        if let characteristics = service.characteristics {
            for char in characteristics {
                let messageToSend = "HelloWorld!"
                peripheral.writeValue(messageToSend.data(using: .utf8)!, for: char, type: .withResponse)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How to for:char error , characteristic: CBCharacteristic how can I reach

Comment: Two run write request how to one request  ?

Comment: Optional(Error Domain=CBATTErrorDomain Code=3 "Writing is not permitted." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Writing is not permitted.})

Comment: @EnesOzel Instead of **.withResponse** try **.withoutResponse**

Comment: [CoreBluetooth] WARNING: Characteristic <CBCharacteristic: 0x282461ec0, UUID = 6D92661D-F429-4D67-929B-28E7A9780912, properties = 0x8, value = (null), notifying = NO> does not specify the "Write Without Response" property - ignoring response-less write return message

Comment: Optional(Error Domain=CBATTErrorDomain Code=3 "Writing is not permitted." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Writing is not permitted.})

Comment: Optional(Error Domain=CBATTErrorDomain Code=13 "The value's length is invalid." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The value's length is invalid.})

Comment: @EnesOzel I never had this problem: "The value's length is invalid".
Which device are you trying to communicate with?

Comment: let messageToSend = "HelloWorld!" 
Working outside